# How can I get started in molecular biology?

Tags: molecular-biology, synthetic-biology

I have a background in computer science and math and am interested in learning molecular / synthetic biology - what resources do people recommend?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, opinion-based questions like this are not appropriate for this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: imo reference request and book recommendation questions are valid question. For people from one background may face tantalizing experience in someother discipline  while the required 'prior research' before asking question. so imo its okay to provide context dependent answers to help clear up confusions to asker and other people at similar situations.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused We have a tag wiki that addresses what we expect for "book recommendation"-style questions. https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info This one does not seem to follow those guidelines, and I'd probably vote to close it as a regular user. I will defer using my diamond power, though, unless I see it gets 4 votes to close from others.

Comment: @tyersome: Also, if you prefer physical books and have a state university or community college conveniently nearby, many of them have "community borrower" options for their libraries.

Answer (score 2):

**First develop a background of basic highschool chemistry, basic biochemistry and basic genetics.**

What is molecular biology: Molecular biology has 2 definitions. A broader definition is molecular basis of life. That is indistinguishable from biochemistry. The second definition is how does genetic information flows through 
 molecular mechanism. The secod one is a more specific definition of molecular biology and how it differs from biochemistry.

Its good to develop some background in biochemistry and genetics because concepts of molecular biology comes from biochemistry and genetics.

**A quick start through biochemistry:**

1. Lippincott's illustrated review on biochemistry.
2. Harpers's illustrated review on biochemistry
3. **Organic chemistry by Solomons and Fryhle (especially stereochemistry portion)**.

then go through gradually more detailed book, such as biochemistry by Lubert Stryer.

**Parallelly go through Genetics book such as**

1. **Principle of genetics by Hartl and Jones**
2. Gene IX by Benjamin Lewin
3. Principles of genetics by Snustad *et al.*
4. iGenetics by peter J. Russell
5. Concept of genetics by Benjamin pearce
6. **Genomes 3 by T A Brown**
7. **Principles of gene manipulation and genomics by RM Twyman and Sandy B Primrose.**

Each book has a different perspective. it will help a clearer picture of different concepts.

**Some basic molecular biology books:**

1. Molecular bioloy- principle of Genome function: by Nancy Craig *et al*.
2. Molecular biology by RF Weaver.
3. **Fundamental molecular biology - Lizabeth Allison**
4. Princiles of molecular biology by Barton and Tropp.

**For a more cellular approach and bigger picture see cell biology based molecular biology books viz.**

1. **Cell biology by Pollard, Earnshaw *et al*.**
2. Cell biology by Gerald Karp
3. Lewins' CELL by Plopper *et al*.
4. The Cell- a molecular approach- by Geoffrey M. Cooper.